# Kentico Xperience 13 -Migration to VS 17.5.2 & errors

Tags: kentico

I have developed a website using Xperience 13, targeting .Net6 and it was working fine for more than a year.
Yesterday, I updated my Visual Studio to 17.5.2 which also installed .Net 7, etc. I opened my live site in this new updated VS, rebuilt everything and my application does not work anymore either with IIS or IIS Express. I have no error in VS, it is just that I can not run it anymore.

I keep getting the following error in the browser:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
CMS.Membership.Internal.VirtualContextAuthenticationConfiguration.get_Audience()

DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor()' on type 'VirtualContextRequestPrincipalRetriever'.
Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.BoundConstructor.Instantiate()

DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating λ:Kentico.Web.Mvc.Internal.IRequestPrincipalRetriever[] -> Kentico.Content.Web.Mvc.VirtualContextRequestPrincipalRetriever.
Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action<ResolveRequestContext> next)
```

I tried uninstalling .Net 7, reinstalling VS etc... but my Kentico site does not work anymore.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: .NET7 is not supported yet. But still, I updated my VS to 17.5.2, changed the target framework to .NET7, using the sample Dancing Goat Core project - everything works fine. I would say it is a configuration issue. Is your presentation URL correct?